# Finding the maximum of a curve scipy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, max

I have fitted curve to a set of data points. I would like to know how to find the maximum point of my curve and then I would like to annotate that point (I don't want to use by largest y value from my data to do this). I cannot exactly write my code but here is the basic layout of my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,4,16,4,1]

def f(x, p1, p2, p3):
    return p3*(p1/((x-p2)**2 + (p1/2)**2))   

p0 = (8, 16, 0.1) # guess perameters 
plt.plot(x,y,"ro")
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0)
plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt))
```

Also is there a way to find the peak width?

Am I missing a simple built in function that could do this? Could I differentiate the function and find the point at which it is zero? If so how?

Comment: have you tried `max(y)` or `y.max()` if `y` is a numpy array?

Comment: it is an array but I have been asked to find the maximum of the curve not the maximum data point in the array.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. That's pure mathematics. To find the maximum of a function, you need to calculate its derivative

Comment: Yes and for the maximum point I set the derivative of the function to zero. I already stated in my question "Could I differentiate the function and find the point at which it is zero? If so how?"

Comment: your function `f` is maximal when `x = p2` and its value at that point is `4*p3/p1`

Comment: But these values have been "guessed" to fit the data points so python doesn't recognize them.

Comment: After you fit the function, you have a set of parameters p1, p2, p3 that define your fit. The maximum of your fit is at (p2, 4*p3/p1). You can use whatever you want to approximate the answer but this gives you the exact one.

Comment: That will not work as p1, p2 and p3 are undefined.

Comment: what do you think `popt` contains? p1, p2, p3 = popt (if i am not mistaken)

Comment: And how can I remove these from popt to perform the calculations?

Comment: I think I've just answered that question: `p1, p2, p3 = popt`

Comment: I see since popt is an array I can treat p1, p2, and p3 as elements from that array and perform the calculations?

Comment: that is correct: `p1 = popt[0]`, `p2 = popt[1]` and `p3 = popt[2]`. If `popt` has only three elements, these statements are the same as `p1, p2, p3 = popt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you fit to find the best parameters to maximize your function, you can find the peak using `minimize_scalar` (or one of the other methods from `scipy.optimize`).

Note that in below, I've shifted `x[2]=3.2` so that the peak of the curve doesn't land on a data point and we can be sure we're finding the peak to the curve, not the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, minimize_scalar

x = [1,2,3.2,4,5]
y = [1,4,16,4,1]

def f(x, p1, p2, p3):
    return p3*(p1/((x-p2)**2 + (p1/2)**2))   

p0 = (8, 16, 0.1) # guess perameters 
plt.plot(x,y,"ro")
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0)

# find the peak
fm = lambda x: -f(x, *popt)
r = minimize_scalar(fm, bounds=(1, 5))
print "maximum:", r["x"], f(r["x"], *popt)  #maximum: 2.99846874275 18.3928199902

x_curve = np.linspace(1, 5, 100)
plt.plot(x_curve, f(x_curve, *popt))
plt.plot(r['x'], f(r['x'], *popt), 'ko')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course, rather than optimizing the function, we could just calculate it for a bunch of x-values and get close:

```
x = np.linspace(1, 5, 10000)
y = f(x, *popt)
imax = np.argmax(y)
print imax, x[imax]     # 4996 2.99859985999
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using `sympy`, it's pretty easy. Assuming the code you posted has already been run:

```
import sympy

sym_x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
sym_f = f(sym_x, *popt)
sym_df = sym_f.diff()
solns = sympy.solve(sym_df)  # returns [3.0]
```

Comment: Ah... that does work thank you! Is there a similar way you may know of  using scipy?