# How do I find the peak of a fitted Gaussian curve?

Tags: python, gaussian

So I've fitted a Gaussian curve to some very noisy data. I was wondering how I'd go about finding the coordinates of the peak of the Gaussian line?

```
def fit_func(x,a,mu,sig,m,c):
            gauss = a*sp.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sig**2))
            line = m*x+c
            return gauss + line            
        
        initial_guess=[160,mean,sd,2,100]
        po,po_cov=sp.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func,x,y,initial_guess)
```

This is the code I've used to fit that Gaussian. Would I have to add more to this? Or just something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the maximum of a curve scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954153/finding-the-maximum-of-a-curve-scipy)

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example that we can execute on our machines? In your example code, the variables `mean`, `sd`, `sp`, `x`, and `y` are all undefined.

I realize `sp` stands for scipy, but you should include the import as well:
`import scipy as sp`.

Answer (score 0):

For a normal distribution, the peak will be located at the mean, so the peak coordinates would be (mu, a) for an expression like `gauss = a*exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sig**2))`. For your case, you also added a linear function, so the global maxima will be either at plus or minus infinity. There will be also a local maximum near the mean of the gaussian distribution, you can find an analytical expression for this taking the derivative of the whole expression and equaling to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a vector of the fitted values, you can use `np.argmax` to do that. Include `import numpy as np` at the beginning of your code and use:

```py
fitted = fit_func(x,po[0],po[1],po[2],po[3],po[4]) # fitted curve
max_at = x[np.argmax(fitted)] # 125.0
plt.plot(x, fitted, label='Fit results')
plt.axvline(x = max_at, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Apparently the fitted curve achieves its (local) maximum at 125.0.